# How to assign user for Celery tasks?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, django-signals

I'm planning a project that will make use of Celery tasks that will perform CRUD operations on my models. In addition, I have Signals in place that will listen for those CRUD operations and I want to specifically log that it was a Celery task (or a Celery task user) performing the operation.

So would I accomplish assigning a User to my Celery workers so that whenever they interact with my models I can track that?

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Location)
def location_pre_save(sender, instance, update_fields=None, **kwargs):
    try:
        old_location = Location.objects.get(id=instance.id)
        # Log Celery user has updated this Location
    except Location.DoesNotExist:
        # Log Celery user has created this Location
```

Comment: Use the django-currentuser library. It provides the functionality you require.

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to achieve with this design, but FYI usage of django signals is usually an antipattern and is meant to be used only in cases when you do not control the workflow. The easiest way to achieve what you want it to pass user_id explicitly to the task, you can get it from `request.user.id`

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev Celery tasks do not get a request object. They are two entirely separate things. Celery is used as a task queue so there's some things it does on the side and it updates my objects. Where does it say Django Signals are an anti pattern? How else would you listen for all changes on your models? Why exactly is that an anti pattern?

Comment: In official docs it say that https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/signals/ - "Where possible you should opt for directly calling the handling code, rather than dispatching via a signal." You can find more information on the internet. Regarding `request.user`, I know that task do not have it in their scope by default, but as I've written in my initial comment you can pass them explicitly, like any other task argument.

Comment: There is no User when running Celery. There's an actor though, which you can set explicitly to a user, which would answer my original question. Regarding the anti pattern, if it's unreliable - why have the feature at all? The only alternative is to make the necessary Logs at each section of the code i'm altering objects? That's a lot of extra code I need to write.

Comment: Yes, but sometimes extra code is necessary to provide clarity to what is actually happening to avoid auto-magical funcationality

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev So then again, why have Signals in the first place if it's bad practice?

Comment: It is for cases when you do not have access to the code that will trigger the function call. For example, if you are designing a third-party app for django. The python Zen states, "Explicit is better than implicit" . Signals hide the business logic, which means that the developer that comes to read the code will not know at a glance that there is a lot of additional steps happening and it may cause problems.